# cyrus-makedirs or mkimap missing on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, cyrus, ubuntu-14.04

The Cyrus manual says that `tools/mkimap` should be run to configure the directories. It appears that this command does not not exist, however.

With a bit of research it looks like there is a debian/Ubuntu version of this called `cyrus-makedirs` (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/cyrus-makedirs.8.html), but that doesn’t appear to be a valid package name, and it looks like it should have already been installed by the meta package, but the command does not exist.

Cyrus was installed via package. What is the proper was to run this command (or make the mail spool dirs) on Ubuntu 14.04 with packaged Cyrus?

Answer (score 0):

I installed cyrus using apt-get on Ubuntu 14.04 and then makedirs is located in:

`/usr/lib/cyrus/bin`

I created the imap folders using:

```
su cyrus -c '/usr/lib/cyrus/bin/makedirs /etc/cyrus/imapd.conf'
```

Hope that helps.